# clear base workspace variable from within function

Tags: matlab

With the following code I've added variables into the base workspace:

```
function data_startup()
bdclose all;
data=load(fullfile('B', 'C', 'data.mat')); 
file_variables=fieldnames(data);% get the field names as cell array
for ii=1:length(file_variables)
     assignin('base', file_variables{ii}, data.(file_variables{ii}));
end
```

Now, I would like to clear variables from the base workspace, I've tried :

```
evalin('base','clear file_variables');
```

But this is not working :(

Comment: Just a sidenote. If you have the choice I would recommend sticking to the normal workspace. Consider just using a function with output arguments (or otherwise a script).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to clear the variable with name `file_variables`, which probably doesn't exist. What you want is:

```
evalin('base',['clear' sprintf(' %s',file_variables{:})]);
```

If you want to understand what's going on: run and debug this line in your function, then inspect the outcome of

```
['clear' sprintf(' %s',file_variables{:})]
```

which will be the command run by `evalin`.

### More info:

`[a  b  c]` concatenates the strings in `a`,`b` and `c`, because the strings themselves are `1xN` arrays.
`{:}` returns the cell array as a comma separated list which is then inputted to `sprintf`, more info on this [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-13).

Comment: could you give more information please, this is working but just to understand , why [] and {:} ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

The above does not work. I do not know why. Functions gives no hints.

But here is a solution that works:

```
clear_names = fieldnames(Data.(itv{i}));   %Get fieldnames to be deleted
feval(@clear,clear_names{:})
```

The variable `clear_names` is a cell of strings

Gruss

Comment: Gunther Struyf's solution does not work for me, too. But `evalin('base',['clearvars'...)` works instead of `evalin('base',['clear'...)`.

Comment: It probably doesn't work, because OP asked for code to clear all the variables in the array `file_variables` from the base workspace. If you're trying to clear other variables than that from another workspace, of course you're gonna need some changes. btw: instead of `feval(@clear,clear_names{:})`, you could've just used `clear(clear_names{:})` (as documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#bt09bdn-1)). This is also no answer to OP's question, hence the downvote

Answer (score 1):

To clear all base variables close all matlab windows and clear command window.

I called it wipe.m

```
function wipe
clc;
bdclose all;
close all;
imtool close all;
evalin('base','clear all');
```

My very first contribution to stackoverflow

Doogie

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) for more details.